# Rate Exceeded on AWS Lambda Using API Gateway and serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

When I try to invoke a method that has a HTTP event it results in `500 Internal  server  error`.

On CloudWatch logs it shows `Recoverable error occurred (Rate Exceeded.)`

When I try invoke a function without lambda it executes with response.

Here is my  serverless config:

[image: config]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set your Lambda's `reservedConcurrency` to 0. This will prevent your Lambda from ever being invoked. Setting it to 0 is usually useful when your functions are getting invoked but you're not sure why and you want to stop it right away.

If you want to have it invoked, change `reservedConcurrency` to a positive integer (by default, it can be a positive integer <= 1000, but you can increase this limit by contacting AWS) or simply remove the `reservedConcurrency` attribute from your .yml file as it will use the default values.

Why would one ever use `reservedConcurrency` anyways? Well, let's say your Lambda functions are triggered by requests from API Gateway. Let's say you get 400 (peak hours) requests/second and, upon every request, two other Lambda functions are triggered, one to generate a thumbnail for a given image and one to insert some metadata in DynamoDB. You'd have, in theory, 1200 Lambda functions running at the same time (given all of your Lambda functions finish their execution in less than a second). This would lead to throttling as the default concurrent execution for Lambda functions is 1000. But is the thumbnail generation as important as the requests coming from API Gateway? Very likely not as it's naturally an eventually consistent task, so you could set `reservedConcurrency` on the thumbnail Lambda to only 200, so you wouldn't use up your concurrency, meaning other functions would be able to spin up to do something more useful at a given point in time (in our example, receiving HTTP requests is more important than generating thumbnails). The other 800 left concurrency could then be split between the function triggered from API Gateway and the one that inserts data into DynamoDB, thus preventing throttling for the important stuff and keeping the not-so-important-stuff eventually consistent.